# Unwind Segue to save into a collection view

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have followed a tutorial on developer.apple.com to create a recipe app in Xcode with swift in a table view. I have started to convert to a collection view but struggled to code the function correctly for unwinding and savind data changes of the recipes.

Could anyone help with how to adjust the code? Currently, it doesn't like the members of the `selectedindexpath` being .row. There are already functions for `saveMeals`

#### Errors

[image: Error]

```
//MARK: Actions
@IBAction func unwindToMealList(sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    if let sourceViewController = sender.source as? MealViewController, let meal = sourceViewController.meal {
        
    if let selectedIndexPath =  collectionView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        // Update an existing meal.
        meals[selectedIndexPath.row] = meal
        collectionView.reloadRows(at: [selectedIndexPath], with: .none)
    }
    else {
        // Add a new meal.
        let newIndexPath = IndexPath(row: meals.count, section: 0)
        
        meals.append(meal)
         collectionView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath], with: .automatic)
    }
    // Save the meals.
    saveMeals()
    }
}
```

[enter image description here][2]

```
//MARK: Actions
    @IBAction func unwindToMealList(sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {
        if let sourceViewController = sender.source as? MealViewController, let meal = sourceViewController.meal {
            
            if let selectedIndexPath = collectionView?.numberOfSections{
                // Update an existing meal.
                meals[selectedIndexPath] = meal
                collectionView?.reloadData()
            }
            else {
                // Add a new meal.
                meals.append(meal)
                saveMeals()
                collectionView?.reloadData()

                       }
    }
    
    


}
```

This is the Meal Class

```
import UIKit
import os.log

class Meal: NSObject, NSCoding {
    
    //MARK: Properties
    
    var name: String
    var photo: UIImage?
    var method: String?
    var ingredients: String?
    
    
    
    //MARK: Archiving Paths
    
    static let DocumentsDirectory = FileManager().urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    static let ArchiveURL = DocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("meals")
    
    
    //MARK: Types
    
    struct PropertyKey {
        static let name = "name"
        static let photo = "photo"
        static let method = "method"
        static let ingredients = "ingredients"
        
        
    }
    
    //MARK: Initialization
    
    init?(name: String, photo: UIImage?, method: String?, ingredients: String?) {
        
        // The name must not be empty
        guard !name.isEmpty else {
            return nil
        }
        
        
        
        // Initialize stored properties.
        self.name = name
        self.photo = photo
        self.method = method
        self.ingredients = ingredients
        
        
    }
    
    //MARK: NSCoding
    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(name, forKey: PropertyKey.name)
        aCoder.encode(photo, forKey: PropertyKey.photo)
        aCoder.encode(method, forKey: PropertyKey.method)
        aCoder.encode(ingredients, forKey: PropertyKey.ingredients)
        
    }
    
    required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        
        // The name is required. If we cannot decode a name string, the initializer should fail.
        guard let name = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.name) as? String else {
            os_log("Unable to decode the name for a Meal object.", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
            return nil
        }
        
        // Because photo is an optional property of Meal, just use conditional cast.
        let photo = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.photo) as? UIImage
        
        let method = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.method) as? String
        
        let ingredients = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.ingredients) as? String
        
        
        
        // Must call designated initializer.
        self.init(name: name, photo: photo, method: method, ingredients: ingredients)
        
    }    }
```

Navigation

```
  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)
        switch(segue.identifier ?? "") {
        case "AddItem":
            os_log("Adding a new meal.", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
        case "ShowDetail":
            guard let mealDetailViewController = segue.destination as? MealViewController else {
                fatalError("Unexpected destination: \(segue.destination)")
            }
            
            guard let selectedMealCell = sender as? MealCollectionViewCell else {
                fatalError("Unexpected sender: \(String(describing: sender))")
            }
            
            guard let indexPath = collectionView?.indexPath(for: selectedMealCell) else {
                fatalError("The selected cell is not being displayed by the table")
            }
            
            let selectedMeal = meals[indexPath.row]
            mealDetailViewController.meal = selectedMeal
            
            
        default:
            fatalError("Unexpected Segue Identifier; \(segue.identifier)")
            
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so first you need to understand that these collectionview properties like indexpath and stuff are only available inside the delegate methods of the collectionview and not outside them.

Now in your code you can do it this way. The add part is easy part. Just add `reloadData` call

so you append your meal in your array list and then call above method

```
meals.append(meal)
saveMeals()
collectionView.reloadData()
```

The tricky part is how do you edit. So in Edit what you can do is in your unwind Segue as you are getting the value of meal, You also need to get some identifier for which meal was edited, maybe a meal id or something.

Then in your arrayList you can edit the object of Meal only for the id which has been edited and then save it. Then call the `collectionView.reloadData()`.

Or you can also do is when you go for an edit, pass the indexpath from itemSelected to the next ViewController and set that as a property. When you do an unwind segue, get that property from something like `sourceViewController.selectedIndexPathProperty` and then use it here the way you were using it so far.

Comment: Thank you. When I edit I am still having trouble with it updating the right cell in the collection view. How can I specifty this

Comment: So in the edit scenario, which way did you go? Did you pass the indexpath.row to next VC and got it back?

Comment: Because I pass the data from the collection view to next detail view controller, I've been using that to ID which item's data is updated during the unwind - added screen of new code to a new answer

Comment: What does your saveMeals method do? ideally call it before reload data if it changes your list. Also in case of edit, you only need to refresh the row for that particular indexpath. and it should work. If it doesn't work, update your code in question and i will have a look

Comment: updated the code, swapping it did not work. I can't seem to get  selectedindexpath.row to work

Comment: Can you also add the code for how you are clicking on one row and then passing the selectedIndexpath to another VC

Comment: added both the meal class and navigation

Comment: Can you explain how you are getting which meal is selected in collectionview. This code doesn't seem correct to me.

Comment: If I update a meal it works the first time and then if I go into a different meal, it updates the original one. It's not changing which cell it updates each time I change a differnet one

Comment: @Harri have you implemented func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)?

Comment: I am assuming you are calling performSegue from there and doing prepareforsegue to add selected item. Now in that method before you call the perform segue save the indexpath in global variable and use that global variable here in your prepareforsegue method to set the selectedIndexPathProperty of destination. Also use the meal object of that global indexpath

Comment: Yes that's how I have created the segue

Comment: let meal = meals[indexPath.row]  is how it defines what indexpath. In a table view the existing meal edit function was meals[selectedIndexPath.row] = meal (row is not a member of a collection view. Is there a subsitutue

Comment: @Harri not sure what you meant by that but indexpath.row is available for collectionview as well. Please add your didSelectCode as well for me to help